# What is the thermodynamic spin-vector distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, fermions, spinors, geometry

### Background

So my understanding is the Fermi-Dirac distribution tells us about the probability of a particular energy state for spinors.  Also, from Spinors and Space-Time Volume $1$ - Penrose and Rindler, Pauli - Chapter $1$, we know spinors can be mapped to spin vectors. (For context [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzYV6VrsHyQ))

### Question

How does one obtain the spin vector distribution corresponding to the Fermi-Dirac distribution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind. The Penrose-Newman formalism is a way of re-writing ordinary classical general relativity in terms of spinor variables. I can presumable use PN to write the Boltzmann equation in terms of spinor variables (although I have not seen this done), but it would not correspond to the distribution of particles obeying Fermi-Dirac statistics (we are just writing x,p in terms of spinor variables). Of course, separate from PN, I can write down a Boltzmann equation for particles with spin (i.e. I have a distribution $f_\sigma(x,p)$, but x,p are ordinary variables.

Comment: Ah .I see. Can you express the Boltzmann equation in terms of spinor variables?

Comment: That's what I was saying:I assume so, but I have not seen it done. What would be the purpose?

Comment: There are many ways of deriving the Boltzmann distribution (without resorting to entropy). I'm wondering how general they are? And if they could be extended to spinors